# tensor products as a quotient - construction

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

A tensor product $N\otimes_R M$ of $R$-modules $N,M$ is defined as $F(N,M)/B(N,M)$, where $B(N,M)$ is defined as the $R$-module generated by the elements $((n_1+n_2)\otimes m)-(n_1\otimes m)-(n_2\otimes m)$ and $(n\otimes (m_1+m_2))-(n\otimes m_1)-(n\otimes m_2)$ and $(rn\otimes m)-r(n\times m)$ and $(n\otimes rm)-r(n\times m)$. Furthermore, $F(N,M)$ is defined as $\bigoplus_{n\in N,m\in M} R\cdot n\otimes m$. What would be an example for $B(N,M)$ given $N,M$?

Is $B(N,M)$ in some cases zero (a zero set) and in other cases $B(N,M)$ contains non-zero elements? I am slightly confused. Can you give an example for $B(N,M)$, which illustrates the relevance of this construction using $B(N,M)$?

Comment: See section $2$ for examples of $B(N,M)$, together with Theorem $3.2$ in K. Conrad's [notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf). He takes an example $N=M=\Bbb R^3$, with $R=\Bbb R$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde where in Section 2 of your link are there examples of $B(M,N)$? I didn't find examples of $B(N,M)$ there.  That section has lots of bilinear maps, but that's not strictly what the elements of $B(N,M)$ really are (special elements in the free $R$-module $F(N,M)$).

Answer (score 1):

Informally spaking, this construction may relate different elements of $F(N,M)$, if the above relationships which span $B(N,M)$ allow for a simplification. For example, in $F(N,M)$, an element such as $((n_1+n_2)\otimes m)-(n_1\otimes m)-(n_2\otimes m)$ is non-zero, but in the tensor product $F(N,M)/B(N,M)$ the latter element is an element of $B(N,M)$, so constitutes a zero element in this quotient ring. Technically speaking, the set $F(N,M)$ is spanned by $\{n\otimes_R m|n\in N,m\in M\}$. By quotienting by $B(N,M)$, the above relationships between the elements of $F(N,M)$ are introduced. Consider $$r(n\otimes m)+s(n\otimes m)+B(N,M)$$ with $s\in R$. We see that this element is $(r+s)(n\otimes m)+B(N,M)$, since $r(n\otimes m)+s(n\otimes m)$ can be written as

$$r(n\otimes m)+s(n\otimes m)=r(n\otimes m)+s(n\otimes m)+\underbrace{((r+s)(n\otimes m)-r(n\otimes m)-s(n\otimes m))}_{\in B(N,M)},$$

by using a combination of the above relationships which generate $B(N,M)$.